# Correct pronunciation for 「シドニー支社に」

Tags: pronunciation

I heard two different pronunciations for「シドニー支社に」

> **A:** *shidoni issha ni*　**(しどに　いっしゃ　に)**
>
> **B:** *shidonii shisha ni*　**(しどにい　ししゃ　に)**

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The /i/ in ししゃ may be devoiced because it's surrounded by two voiceless consonants, making it sound like what you might spell as "shhha" with an elongated hissing sound. I think this is what you heard.

With or without this devoicing, the last /i/ in シドニー is long, though.

Answer (score 2):

The extension syllable `ー` only applies to *katagana* and always come after another syllable. Therefore, the `ー` should be part of `ニー`, i.e., `シドニー` (Sidney / Sydney) should be considered a single group. Therefore,

> B: shidonii shisha ni　(しどにい　ししゃ　に)

would be correct.